# Добавить правило для .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod_rewrite

Есть рабочий .htaccess  с набором правил. Мне надо добавить обработку одного параметра и "не сломать" другие правила. Нужно, чтобы адрес вида site.com/ru/ *преобразовывался в site.com/*?lang=ru

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^/es/(.+)$ /$1

# links with .html appended ##

RewriteRule ^members/delete/(.*)/(.*).html$ /delete_file.php?delete_id=$1&file_id=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^files/(.*).html$ /download.php?file_id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^delete/(.*)/(.*).html$ /delete_file.php?delete_id=$1&file_id=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^info/(.*).html$ /info_file.php?info_id=$1 [L]

# links with .html removed #
RewriteRule ^members/delete/(.*)/(.*)$ /delete_file.php?delete_id=$1&file_id=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^files/(.*)$ /download.php?file_id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^delete/(.*)/(.*)$ /delete_file.php?delete_id=$1&file_id=$2 [L]

# normal links #
RewriteRule ^members/(.*)$ /$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^help/(.*)$ /$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^get/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ /get_file.php?file_id=$1&time=$2&filename=$3 [L]

# error docs #
ErrorDocument 404 /error_404.php
```

Моих познаний тут не хватает, ломаются последние 3 правила

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решено

```
RewriteRule ^ru/(.*)$ /$1 [E=lang:ru]
```